# Twilio Gather Action on PHP Hosted on AWS S3 Does Not Execute

Tags: php, amazon-s3, twilio

Action in gather points to aws hosted php file. I think syntax is correct but file doesn't execute. Is that expected ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather action="https://s3.amazonaws.com/chumbucketv1/process_gather.php" method="GET">
        <Say>
            Please enter your account number,
            followed by the pound sign
        </Say>
    </Gather>
    <Say>We didn't receive any input. Goodbye!</Say>
</Response>
```

Comment: the action url is wrong, there is a missing space between `<?php` and `echo`

Comment: I tried adding a space but still receive same application error.

Comment: `<?phpecho "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
echo "<Response><Say>You entered " . $_REQUEST['Digits'] . "</Say></Response>";
?>` no space, which is why i can download the file

Comment: Sorry if I am misunderstanding, but I don't see a missing space and I am still not seeing the file execute.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

AWS S3 is a file store, not a PHP application server. No PHP will be executed by files stored in S3, when you make a request to that URL S3 will just return the file to you.

You need to host that PHP on a server that will execute the code. You could host the code on something like [AWS Lightsail](https://aws.amazon.com/websites/) instead?

Comment: Thanks. How would the gather action tag be specified if say the php file is hosted on lightsail ? <Gather action =...."> ?

Comment: It should be specified no different to any other way that PHP code would be specified. Your hosting platform should not define the way you write your code, you just need to host it on something that will execute your code, not S3.

Comment: How do I upload the php to lightsail so that twilio can access it with a url like : https://s3.amazonaws.com/chumbucketv1/process_gather.php (but for lightsail)?

Comment: I have not used Lightsail (and it is just a suggestion, since you were already trying to use AWS). I would follow the Lightsail documentation to get yourself setup. This article might help to start: https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en/articles/compare-options-choose-lightsail-instance-image